# Cannot convert System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
List <PhraseAndScore> ps = db2.Query<PhraseAndScore>(select).ToList();
List<PhraseAndScore> psNoHidden = ps.Where(x => x.Hidden == false);
```

I would like the psNoHidden to give me the contents of ps but where the Hidden property is false. When I compile it's giving this error. Is it because I am doing the .ToList() too early or am I doing it correctly and I should do something else?

> Error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type
>   `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Japanese.PhraseAndScore>` to
>   `System.Collections.Generic.List<Japanese.PhraseAndScore>`. An
>   explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) (CS0266)

Comment: Just add another ToList at the end of Where clause. Obviously IEnumerable is just interface, it will not imlicitly convert to concrete implementation.

Comment: Remember that `IEnumerable<T>` isn't necessarily a `List<T>`. It could be a `Queue<T>`, `Stack<T>` or any number of other things.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add a call to `ToList()` method after the `Where(...)` call, as in: `ps.Where(x => x.Hidden == false).ToList();`.

`Where()` will return an `IEnumerable` object, which can or cannot be a list: the compiler doesn't know if it is a `List` or not, so it throws an error at you. Calling ToList() ensures the `IEnumerable` gets transformed into a `List` for you.

Answer (score 4):

When you call `ToList` on `IQueryable` you are materializing your data into process memory. You can fix your error with two possible solutions:

```
List <PhraseAndScore> ps = db2.Query<PhraseAndScore>(select).ToList();
List<PhraseAndScore> psNoHidden = ps.Where(x => x.Hidden == false).ToList();
```

or

```
var ps = db2.Query<PhraseAndScore>(select);
List<PhraseAndScore> psNoHidden = ps.Where(x => x.Hidden == false).ToList();
```

In second case your `Where` call will be transferred to your database and converted into SQL `where` clause